# Xcode 7.3.1 - SVN : Couldn't communicate with a helper application

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

Using Xcode 7.3.1, I get the following error when trying to commit any changes to my project which is under SVN source control

"The working copy "ProjectName" failed to commit files.
Couldn't communicate with a helper application"

My guess would be it's failing to locate / execute the "svn" binary under the hood, but it does seem strange that other SVN actions in Xcode work fine (Source Control -> History... happily shows all previous commits etc, which would suggest it is able to communicate with the SVN server just fine)

There are other similar problems to this on the site, but all are either related to Git projects or are unanswered

Comment: Hi Jim, did you find solution?

Comment: @benhi - afraid not - we gave up on it in the end and just back the project up on Google Drive and manually merge stuff (luckily it's not a very active project and there's a max of two people working on it at once!). Good luck :)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but, this comment may help somebody. 

I too encountered this issue and found that I am trying to commit a file which is added recently to the project, but deleted the file from finder (with ! mark against the file while commit).  I removed that file from project and could commit successfully.

Answer (score 0):

We got this problem when adding a new localization. We are using xCode 8.2.1

We found that the graphics files with a @ character in them caused the problem. SVN doesn't like @. When you do an SVN operation on a file with a @ in its name you have to add another @ at the end of the command. Seemingly xCode is not taking this into consideration when interacting with SVN.

The workaround for this is to temporarily move  your .svn file from your project directory, do the work in xCode, then move your .svn file back and manually update SVN using the non-xCode interface of your choice.